# Non linear inductor in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, inductor, non-linear

I am trying to construct a non linear inductor in LTspice and have a question regarding the two plots provided below. In the first image current is swept from -30A to 30A in steps. The result yields the required behavior where the initial inductance is 500uH and with 27A peak current the left over inductance is around 40 uH.
[image]
However, when using the same flux function measuring inductance across L1 the obtained result shows that with zero current the inital inductance is around 15mH, this is not correct.
[image]
I wonder if there is something I may do not understand here.
Spice netlist is provided below:

```
L1 ind1 0 Flux=0.007*tanh(0.072*x)
I1 0 ind1 PWL(0 0 1 30)
I2 0 ind2 {I_DC} AC {1/(2*pi)}
L2 ind2 0 Flux=0.007*tanh(0.072*x)
.tran 1
.step param I_DC -30 30 0.1
;.ac list 1
.backanno
.end
```

Comment: BTW L is usually rated for the current value at 90% Lmax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second analysis is in the frequency domain, so the results that you get are a function of frequency, first and foremost. You are using the card `.ac list 1`, which means you are evaluating the frequency response at 1 Hz, for a variation in the source's DC value.

If you'll change the analysis to be `.tran 10` and set the current source to be `sin 0 1 1` (unity amplitude, 1 Hz), you'll see that the voltage across the inductor will be `~3.16 mV` peak. If you now divide this by `2*pi` it will show `~504 uV` peak, which is the same as what you got there.

Don't forget that, if you want a `.DC` analysis it will fail since that only evaluates the operating point, without any dynamics involved, and the inductor is considered a short. If you want a `.TRAN` analysis then you will get the dynamic variation, provided that it varies much slower than the variation, itself. And an `.AC` analysis will give you a response as a function of frequency, and if you perform one for 0 Hz (only works with `.ac list 0`) you will get exactly what a `.DC` analysis will get you: an operating point with shorted inductors and opened capacitors; otherwise you'll need to take frequency into account.